# Suspected syntax issue in php array for use with data objects

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

Using the guidelines [suggested by netnuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for the use of Data Objects for Database access, specifically in relation to unnamed placeholders

```
# the data we want to insert
$data = array('Cathy', '9 Dark and Twisty Road', 'Cardiff');
$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO folks (name, addr, city) values (?, ?, ?);
$STH->execute($data);
```

unfortunately seems to produce a parse error for the code

```
# the data we want to insert
$data = array($first_name, $second_name, $email_from, $telephone, $dateofbirth, $addresslone, $addressltwo, $townnm, $countynm, $typeapp, $issubscribed);
$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO members (fname, sname, email, phone, dob, addressl1, addressl2, town, county, type, subscribed) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$STH->execute($data);
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /HTMLADDRESS.php on line 82

Line 82 is specifically that which begins with the assignment of the variable $DBH to $STH

I have also executed this code with all variables in the data array wrapped in quotes, with the same result.

Comment: If you don't close your quotes, then you will get syntax errors

Comment: not to mention you're not even calling a method with $DBH

Comment: @MarkBaker Hi! Could you show me where they aren't closed? Note that there seems to be a typo in the code I have quoted from the netnuts website.

Comment: the quotes are closed, the error its the lack of method call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or
>   T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /HTMLADDRESS.php on line 82

is telling you is that after the `->` it wasnt expecting a `(`, thats right because there should be a method call.

it should be

```
# the data we want to insert
$data = array($first_name, $second_name, $email_from, $telephone, $dateofbirth, $addresslone, $addressltwo, $townnm, $countynm, $typeapp, $issubscribed);
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO members (fname, sname, email, phone, dob, addressl1, addressl2, town, county, type, subscribed) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$STH->execute($data);
```

its an error in netnuts code.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! Now to just iron out the logic errors... :P